# How to optimize PostgreSQL leaderboard window function query

Tags: sql, postgresql, ranking, window-functions, leaderboard

In our API we have a basic ranking / leaderboard functionality, where each client user has its list of "actions" they can perform, each action results in a score and all actions are logged in "actions" table and then each user can ask for the leaderboard of the current month (each month the leaderboard resets). Nothing fancy.

We have two tables: the table with the users and the table with the actions (I've removed non relevant column):

```
> \d client_users
                                           Table "public.client_users"
         Column         |            Type             |                         Modifiers
------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------
 id                     | integer                     | not null default nextval('client_users_id_seq'::regclass)
 app_id                 | integer                     |
 user_id                | character varying           | not null
 created_at             | timestamp without time zone |
 updated_at             | timestamp without time zone |
Indexes:
    "client_users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_client_users_on_app_id" btree (app_id)
    "index_client_users_on_user_id" btree (user_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "client_users_app_id_fk" FOREIGN KEY (app_id) REFERENCES apps(id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "leaderboard_actions" CONSTRAINT "leaderboard_actions_client_user_id_fk" FOREIGN KEY (client_user_id) REFERENCES client_users(id)

> \d leaderboard_actions
                                       Table "public.leaderboard_actions"
     Column     |            Type             |                            Modifiers
----------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------
 id             | integer                     | not null default nextval('leaderboard_actions_id_seq'::regclass)
 client_user_id | integer                     |
 score          | integer                     | not null default 0
 created_at     | timestamp without time zone |
 updated_at     | timestamp without time zone |
Indexes:
    "leaderboard_actions_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_leaderboard_actions_on_client_user_id" btree (client_user_id)
    "index_leaderboard_actions_on_created_at" btree (created_at)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "leaderboard_actions_client_user_id_fk" FOREIGN KEY (client_user_id) REFERENCES client_users(id)
```

The query I am trying to optimize is the following:

```
SELECT
  cu.user_id,
  SUM(la.score) AS total_score,
  rank() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(la.score) DESC) AS ranking
FROM client_users cu
JOIN leaderboard_actions la ON cu.id = la.client_user_id
WHERE cu.app_id = 8
AND la.created_at BETWEEN '2017-07-01 00:00:00.000000' AND '2017-07-31 23:59:59.999999'
GROUP BY cu.id
ORDER BY total_score DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Note: client_users.user_id is a varchar "human id", the tables are joined with the foreign key on client_user.id (the naming is not great, i know :D)

**Basically I'm asking PostgreSQL to give me the top 20 users ranked by the sum of the score of their individual actions in the current month.**

As you can see from the query plan is not that fast:

```
Limit  (cost=8641.96..8642.05 rows=20 width=52) (actual time=135.544..135.560 rows=20 loops=1)
 Output: cu.user_id, (sum(la.score)), (rank() OVER (?)), cu.id
 ->  WindowAgg  (cost=8641.96..8841.42 rows=44326 width=52) (actual time=135.543..135.559 rows=20 loops=1)
       Output: cu.user_id, (sum(la.score)), rank() OVER (?), cu.id
       ->  Sort  (cost=8641.96..8664.12 rows=44326 width=44) (actual time=135.538..135.539 rows=20 loops=1)
             Output: (sum(la.score)), cu.id, cu.user_id
             Sort Key: (sum(la.score)) DESC
             Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 1451kB
             ->  HashAggregate  (cost=7824.77..7957.75 rows=44326 width=44) (actual time=130.938..133.124 rows=10411 loops=1)
                   Output: sum(la.score), cu.id, cu.user_id
                   Group Key: cu.id
                   ->  Hash Join  (cost=5858.66..7780.44 rows=44326 width=40) (actual time=50.849..111.346 rows=79382 loops=1)
                         Output: cu.id, cu.user_id, la.score
                         Hash Cond: (la.client_user_id = cu.id)
                         ->  Index Scan using index_leaderboard_actions_on_created_at on public.leaderboard_actions la  (cost=0.09..1736.77 rows=69494 width=8) (actual time=0.020..33.773 rows=79382 loops=1)
                               Output: la.id, la.client_user_id, la.rule_id, la.score, la.created_at, la.updated_at, la.success
                               Index Cond: ((la.created_at >= '2017-07-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (la.created_at <= '2017-07-31 23:59:59.999999'::timestamp without time zone))
                         ->  Hash  (cost=5572.11..5572.11 rows=81846 width=36) (actual time=50.330..50.330 rows=81859 loops=1)
                               Output: cu.user_id, cu.id
                               Buckets: 131072  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 6583kB
                               ->  Seq Scan on public.client_users cu  (cost=0.00..5572.11 rows=81846 width=36) (actual time=0.014..34.539 rows=81859 loops=1)
                                     Output: cu.user_id, cu.id
                                     Filter: (cu.app_id = 8)
                                     Rows Removed by Filter: 46610
Planning time: 1.276 ms
Execution time: 136.176 ms
(26 rows)
```

To give you an idea of the sizes:

- client_users has around 128471 rows and only 81860 targeted by the query (*app_id = 8*)
- leaderboard_actions has 1609992 rows and 79435 in the current month

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Don't agree with you: plan *is* fast, given the amount of information you're requesting.

Answer (score 1):

The plan you get is actually more than *reasonably* fast.

You can help your plans with (yet) another couple of indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_client_users_app_id_user  
    ON client_users(app_id, id, user_id) ;

CREATE INDEX idx_leaderboard_actions_3 
    ON leaderboard_actions(created_at, client_user_id, score) ;
```

After creating both indexes, perform a

```
VACUUM ANALYZE client_users;
VACUUM ANALYZE leaderboard_actions;
```

These indexes will allow (most probably) the query to be executed reading only them (and not the table `client_users` nor the `leaderboard_actions`). All needed information is already there. The plan should show some `Index Only Scan`.

You can find a ***simulation*** of your scenario at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=a6a898f5f216c63d47c89d3928a46502)*. 
**There is a 30% improvement on execution time.** You might get similar improvements in your ***actual*** scenario.

Comment: Thank you very much for the input. It seems to be working perfectly. I'll keep an eye on the write queries to see if they slow down but they shouldn't much.

Comment: Maintaining the indexes will add some overhead on all the `INSERT`s and `UPDATE`s (specially the ones modifying any indexed column). Using the indexes will make more or less sense depending on whether your scenario is either *read-heavy* or *write-heavy*. In the first case, you'll notice a global improvement, in the second, probably the overhead doesn't pay off.